# Stationary Points, about a certain Curve

Tags: derivatives, stationary-point

Curve $C$ has an equation of :
$$y = 1 + \frac {2x+p}{(x-2)(x+3)} $$
where p is a constant

Find the range of values of p for which $C$ has more than one stationary point

I answered
$$y'= \frac{2(x^2+x-6)-(2x+p)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x-6)^2}$$
$$y'= 0$$ so
$$0 = 2(x^2+x-6)-(2x+p)(2x+1)$$
$$0 = 2x^2+2px+p+12$$

what to do next?

Comment: You must use the quadratic fomula

Comment: i must use the abc rule? sorry i don't get it, may you explain more to me? thanks

Comment: I got this derivative: $$f'(x)=-{\frac {2\,px+2\,{x}^{2}+p+12}{ \left( x-2 \right) ^{2} \left( x+3
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: i see, i got it wrong at the p+12, then what to do next? if $f'(x) = 0$, then how to get the appropriate x value for getting the p range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to solve
$$2x^2+2px+p+12=0$$ use the quadratic formula for
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ this is $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Thank you, gbu, i get it now